# How to set the border color in PDF forms to none?

Tags: hyperref, forms

I want to set the color of the border for my text fields to be none.
But the parameter doesn't seem to accept none as a value.
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=formname,bordercolor=none,width=6cm] {\mbox{}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Also with the `backgroundcolor` parameter.

Comment: I found the solution below by chance. I am posting this since I think this might be useful for others who might face the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to leave the value empty and use `bordercolor=`.
Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=formname,bordercolor=,width=6cm] {\mbox{}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `bordercolor={1 1 1}` (white) also works, although it is not a documented default.

Comment: @alfC, I don't want it to be white, I want it to be `none`. are you sure the resulting color in the pdf has value `none`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough of the PDF format to know if `bordercolor=` means white or none at the end. What is `none` supposed to mean? Transparent? I don't know if that is supported. Maybe a true `none` is simply to set the `borderwidth=0pt` like the other answer. It cab tested in a colored background.

Comment: @alfC, `none` is a value for color that pdf supports. Yes, the result is transparent (regarding width 0 see [my comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148754/?noredirect=1#comment338015_148758) below).

Comment: `bordercolor={}` as well as `backgroundcolor={}` also works and feels better than just leaving nothing after the `=`.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way is probably to set borderwidth to zero so no border is added. (Leaving bordercolor the empty string doesn't seem to be a supported value as far as I can see, even though it may not give an error message)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=formname,borderwidth=0pt,,width=6cm] {\mbox{}}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this, but this won't work with other parameters like `backgroundcolor` which I want to set to none. Since PDF files support a none/no color value for these parameters the main point is how to access them from `hyperref` and leaving the value empty seems to do exactl that. `hyperref` package is not well-documented AFAIU.

Comment: How do we apply this solution to all the elements?