# How to change the border color of "all" fields in a PDF fillable form?

Tags: hyperref, color, forms

This question is inspired from [How to set the border color in PDF forms to none?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148754/)

From the accepted answer of the above question, for changing the border color of one textfield one can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField[bordercolor=blue]{}
\TextField{}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

How to change the border color of **all** fields through the entire document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine the undocumented `\DefaultOptionsof…` macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\DefaultOptionsofSubmit{print,name=Submit,noexport,bordercolor=blue}
\def\DefaultOptionsofReset{print,name=Reset,noexport,bordercolor=blue}
\def\DefaultOptionsofPushButton{print,bordercolor=blue}
\def\DefaultOptionsofCheckBox{print,bordercolor=blue}
\def\DefaultOptionsofText{print,bordercolor=blue}
\def\DefaultOptionsofListBox{print,bordercolor=blue}
\def\DefaultOptionsofComboBox{print,edit,sort,bordercolor=blue}
\def\DefaultOptionsofPopdownBox{print,bordercolor=blue}
\def\DefaultOptionsofRadio{print,notoggletooff,bordercolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField{}
\TextField{}
\CheckBox{}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I confirm that this answers the question. Let me wait a while before accepting your answer in order to increase the chance of having alternative solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\HyField@SetKeys{<field key-value list>}` to specify default styles for all fields.

Provided that all the per-field default options stored in `\DefaultOptionsof…` do not contain `bordercolor`, `\HyField@SetKeys` truly alters border color for all fields.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\HyField@SetKeys{bordercolor=cyan}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\TextField{}
\TextField{}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I confirm that your solution works too.